# How to calculate and display number of occurrences in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate the number of occurrences each variable occurred across all the samples. I have 20 variables (var1, var2, var3 etc) and 1000 samples (ID 1, 2, 3 etc).

```
df1 :
ID   var1   var2   var3
1    10       57     16               
2    8        66     34               
3    7         0     57               
4    0        90     94               
5    20       44     33
```

How many samples did the species occur in df1 is it to say different from 0 :

```
result :
var1    var2  var3
 4        4      5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
colSums(df1[,2:4]>0)
```

Output:

```
var1 var2 var3 
   4    4    5
```

Answer (score 1):

One brutal solution is with `apply` function

```
apply(df1[ ,2:ncol(df1)], 2, function(x){sum(x != 0)})
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` variant could be:

```
df %>%
 summarise_at(-1, ~ sum(. != 0))

  var1 var2 var3
1    4    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming negative occurrences are an impossibility the sum of a sign solution works.

```
colSums(sign(df1[names(df1) != "ID"]))
```